# How to handle user's request when OAuth Access token expire?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, oauth-2.0

I'm new to ionic & angular, currently trying to build an android app. Using OAUTH 2(also new at here) for resource authorization. Now, stuck at one point & want to know how you peoples handle such issues.

Basically, in my app there 3 different blocks communicate with each other to do the job. These are -

1 - Client-side app(ionic app)

2 - Resource Server

3 - OAuth Server

After successfully, getting the `Access_Token` & `Refresh_Token` from OAuth Server, whenever the Client-side app needs any resource it makes an HTTP request to Resource Server by attaching the `Access_Token` with the request. Then Resource Server verify that `Access_Token` with OAuth server. If `Access_Token` found as valid Resource Server return the desire resource else return error.

So, here my problem is - if `Access_Token` has expired & in Client-side I got the error also from Resource Server, then how I'll get the new `Access_Token` & resend that with a new HTTP request. Because, the moment I'll make an HTTP request for a new `Access_Token`, I'll lose the previous User's Request. Then, after getting the new `Access_Token`, how I'll trigger old HTTP request of the user's to get his/her required resources.

Comment: Have you seen PassportJS?

Comment: @mindparse - nops man.